Can someone with a PhD in the field take the GRE/SAT/AP tests in the same field and pass, without preparation?
I'm curious if someone with a PhD in (say) math can take AP math, SAT Math 2, or GRE math subject test and pass, without preparation. I define "pass" as scoring enough for an "A" grade, or 90th percentile if scoring is based on percentile, or better.
In other words, can someone with a PhD in math be expected to still know undergraduate math and lower well? Given time to study they'll surely have no trouble, but can they do it cold? If the answer is "no", how much more elementary does the exam need to get before the PhD can be expected to pass it cold?
An ideal answer will draw on a large sample size, but if that's not realistic, single case studies are also OK (e.g. "I can do most of it, so passing is not a problem, but I've forgotten/never encountered ___").

Yes, you’re expected to know everything. No exceptions, why do you ask?


AP math

There is no “AP Math,” so I assume you mean AP calculus. Yes, any (recent) math PhD should be able to do calculus competently; I would expect a near perfect score. Even/especially from PhDs in adjacent fields like physics or applied math. Of course, such knowledge may be forgotten if it is not needed; someone who got a PhD 40 years ago and hasn't used calculus since might not do so well.

SAT Math 2

This is no longer a thing. But it used to test precalculus, so yes, this would be even easier.

GRE math subject test

This (not to be confused with the math portion of the GRE general exam) is much harder than the other two, in that it covers undergraduate-level math including higher math. I am confident that most recent PhDs could make a good attempt at most questions without preparation, but I suspect that many would not hit the 90th percentile within the time limit and without external resources. On the analogous physics exam, for example, I’m sure there is stuff about optics and analog circuits that I no longer remember.
Remember, however, that a PhD is a research degree, and that higher math is fundamentally different than high school math. To the extent that PhDs would outperform those with masters degrees or undergraduate degrees only, this is probably due to greater teaching experience or passion for the subject rather than because the PhD itself is good training for such exams.

It's surprising to me that the AP & SAT tests seem to be focused on calculus. There's more to math in high school than calculus, no? I remember summing infinite series, trigonometric identities, conic sections ... Are these topics not tested? If not, why?

Honestly even within calculus I think I don't remember everything. I think I can do most of it, but I've forgotten some corners like integration by parts, especially since Wolfram Alpha. (But I'm not in math.)

Infinite series are normally covered in calculus class. Trigonometric identities are precalculus, and you’ll need them in calculus to solve certain integrals. I suspect physics school is actually better training for calculus than math school; I remember doing integrals and derivatives every day for undergrad and the first part of grad school.

I ran a little GRE prep seminar for some students and definitely had a few questions I couldn't answer. I think I would get around 90%, but there is just a bit too much miscellany asked on the Math GRE to get without practice.

@Allure: It's surprising to me that the AP & SAT tests seem to be focused on calculus. --- The AP tests (traditional AB & BC calculus; there's also a statistics exam and a very recently developed precalculus exam) were/are specifically designed for students to obtain college calculus credit (1st semester for AB test; 1st & 2nd semester for BC test). The SAT test is intended to help select for college admission and is mostly restricted to geometry and first-year algebra, (continued)

perhaps topping out with quadratic equations and quadratic inequalities and some very basic trigonometry. I would suppose that the topics you mentioned -- summing infinite series, trigonometric identities, conic sections -- are studied by too small a percentage of U.S. high school students by the first quarter of their 4th/last year of high school to be all that statistically helpful in selecting for mathematical aptitude rather than mathematical knowledge among the academically upper third of high school students. (continued)

At least, that was probably the original reason. I think in the past few decades, with the huge rise in both test prep that students engage in (something no one really did when I was in high school, at least where I was) and the much greater than "academically upper third" who are now taking the tests, that both the SAT and ACT tests have become more of a knowledge test and less of an aptitude test.

I got a 5 on the AB AP Calculus exam. A long time ago. I got a PhD and have worked in my field for more than 40 years since. There is no way I would do well on an AP Calculus test at this point - I don't do integrals every day or even every month. Sure, I could help my kids with their calculus homework but that is more because I could remember how to approach problems, not all the details. I don't believe I've ever done a trigonometric substitution in my professional life...

(Actually on the BC test - so long ago I'd forgotten).

Shortly after earning my doctorate in math I'd likely have done well on any such standardized test. Now, more than 50 years later and retired, I'd almost certainly do poorly (poooooorly)!

(Returning to this several hours later) Actually, the SAT test has no trigonometry (unless a very recent change). It's the ACT test that has some very basic trigonometry.

My impression of the AP calculus exam (and the GRE math subject exam, to an extent) is that a lot of the questions involve having memorized certain "tricks" (e.g. for integration).  If you have those "tricks" top-of-mind, the problems are not difficult, but if you haven't thought about them in a while, they are going to be quite hard.  I would imagine that a recent physics phd would actually do better on such an exam than a recent math phd---particularly if the math phd is in algebra or number theory or some other field where integration is not a day-to-day event.

@XanderHenderson - even before my PhD, my "trick" was the CRC Math Handbook and the table of integrals in there...

@JonCuster Mine too!
